# Vim: How to exchange key bindings? (bind '|' on '7' key)

Tags: vim, mapping, macvim

Having the German Mac Keyboard Layout, it is a pain to type `|` as it is bound to `<A-7>` and it is hard for me to reach the Alt key.

Thus, I'd like to do the following remapping (exchanging the binding for `|` and `7`):

```
imap 7 <Bar>
imap <A-7> 7
```

The first one works, the second one does not. I have already tried all combinations with `inor` (no remap) but wasn't successful.

Maybe I don't get the concept of remapping. Or I am missing something else.

Comment: By the way. The formatting help does not tell me how to use this key format, making `7` look more like graphical key... looking like [7].

Comment: to enclose 7 in a box use <kbd>7</kbd>. By the way, where was bar bound to `<A-7>`? If it is system shortcut/keyboard option, then just use `inoremap 7 <bar> | inoremap <bar> 7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, some re-mappings that involve modifiers simply don't work in MacVim. The two workarounds I use are:

1. Try a different modifier key, e.g.  or
2. Use Keyboard Maestro (an excellent key mapper for Mac OS X) to do the re-mapping

Comment: Thanks! Keyboard Maestro seems to be the best way to heal this inconsistent and unergonomic Mac keyboard layout (mess).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer you're looking for is:

```
inoremap 7 <bar>
inoremap <bar> 7
```

I use similar bindings to swap my semicolon and colon usage (except mine are not for insert mode):

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;

xnoremap ; :
xnoremap : ;
```

Updated as per Rory O'Kane's suggestion in comments (thanks!).

Comment: Your two `noremap` bindings should be split to use `nnoremap` and `xnoremap` so that they only apply in Normal and Visual modes. `noremap` makes your mappings also apply in [Operator-pending mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Operator-pending-mode) and [Select mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Select-mode), which will break operations like `d;` and the typing of either character in Select mode. See [`:help :map-modes`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-modes).

Comment: Great catch Rory, thanks for pointing that out! Will update my post (and .vimrc).